# ReferenceField is not working react-admin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I am trying to implement a table showing a list of items. I followed the source code at https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/demo

The expected result for the table:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/

[image]

But this is what I'm getting:

[image]

I checked my code over and over and I even tried copying the code at:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/invoices/InvoiceList.tsx
but the customer and order columns just won't render although under the hood, fakeRest is fetching the data:

[image]

so I suspect it is the rendering part that is the issue.

**How to replicate:**

1. git clone https://github.com/CrownKira/digitalace-frontend.git
2. cd to root and run `yarn install` then `yarn dev`
3. point your browser to http://localhost:3000/#/invoices and observe that customer and order are not there even though the data is fetched (see under Network tab) (you can try to switch from json-server to fakeRest (under src/index.ts) and the result is still the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you didn't add the `customers` resource in `App.tsx`. As per the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencefield)

> You must add a `<Resource>` for the reference resource - `react-admin` needs it to fetch the reference data. You can omit the list prop in this reference if you want to hide it in the sidebar menu.

If you add `customers` as a `Resource`, you'd see the referencing and rendering perfectly.

```
<Resource name="customers"/>
```